# find duplicate from getText using Selenium Web-driver

Tags: java, arrays, selenium-webdriver, hashmap, duplicates

This .getText() there are over 100 entry in this I need to find duplicate entry if any.

```
    // This will expand all the arrow
    List<WebElement> arrowdown1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='toggle-children']"));   
    for (int j = 1; j <= arrowdown1.size(); j++) {
        arrowdown1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='toggle-children']"));
        WebElement editicon = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='toggle-children'])[" + j + "]"));
        // This will print all the name text I need to find duplicate text from this 
        //This .getText() there are over 100 entry in this I need to find duplicate entry if any.


        String porfolioName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='mat-checkbox-label'])[" + j + "]")).getText();
        click1(driver, editicon, porfolioName);
```

OUTPUT
From this output I need to find duplicate text 
APAC (L1 - 400)
.APAC NPC (L2 - 2)
.APAC NPC (L3 - 21)
.ANTARCTICA (L4 - AQ)
.BOUVET ISLAND (L4 - BV)
.BRITISH INDIAN OCEAN TERRITORY (L4 - IO)
.CHRISTMAS ISLAND (L4 - CX)
.COCOS (KEELING) ISLANDS (THE) (L4 - CC)
.FRENCH POLYNESIA (L4 - PF)
.FRENCH SOUTHERN TERRITORIES (T (L4 - TF)
.HEARD ISLAND AND MCDONALD ISLA (L4 - HM)
.KIRIBATI (L4 - KI)
.MARSHALL ISLANDS (THE) (L4 - MH)
.MICRONESIA (FEDERATED STATES O (L4 - FM)
.NAURU (L4 - NR)
.NEW CALEDONIA (L4 - NC)
.NIUE (L4 - NU)

Comment: Can you give more details like a sample input string after getText() & your expected output?

Comment: Yes as per above code I get this text below and many more similar I Need to find Duplicate text from this getText list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    private <T> Set<T> findDuplicates(Collection<T> collection) {

    Set<T> duplicates = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    Set<T> uniques = new HashSet<>();

    for(T t : collection) {
        if(!uniques.add(t)) {
            duplicates.add(t);
        }
    }

    return duplicates;
}
```

Or, if you familiar with streams:

```
private <T> Set<T> findDuplicates(Collection<T> collection) {
    Set<T> uniques = new HashSet<>();
    return collection.stream()
        .filter(e -> !uniques.add(e))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```